# Implications of Unruh-inertia to theories of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, cosmology, quantum-gravity

If it turns out to be true that the galaxy rotation curves can be explained away by Unruh modes that become greater than the Hubble scale at accelerations around $10^{-10} m/s^2$ as proposed in [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.7007), what modifications would have to be done to the effective General Relativity equations?

Also, if anyones knows at this early point, what would be the implications for gravity theories that rely on the equivalence principle at a fundamental level, i.e: string theory?

Comment: Nice question, it would be even better to see good answers. ;-)

Comment: I keep hearing that observations of the Bullet Cluster make it very unlikely that dark matter will be explained just by modified gravity. It's not so amazing that modifications of the inverse square law can produce the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tully%E2%80%93Fisher_relation but there's a lot of other data that has to be explained too (e.g. cosmic structure formation).